# Ionic button color change for specific button

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have multiple buttons like this

```
<button id="1" ion-button [color]="btnColor" (click)="btnActivate()">text</button>
<button id="2" ion-button [color]="btnColor" (click)="btnActivate()">text</button>
//etc..



btnColor: string = 'dark';

btnActivate() {
  this.btnColor = 'secondary';
}
```

When user click on any button the color change for **all buttons**. What I want is change the color attribute for the **clicked button only** or change **based on ID** of the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Think all you need is this

Template side :

```
<button #first ion-button color="dark" (click)="btnActivate(first)">text</button>
<button #second ion-button color="dark" (click)="btnActivate(second)">text</button>
```

Component side :

```
btnActivate(ionicButton) {
    ionicButton.color =  'primary';
}
```

Link to working example (please check console / inspect the buttons) :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-change-button-color

Comment: color is special attribute for ionic button, if I changed like this it will not reflect in class.  this class "button-md-dark" will be change to ''button-md-secondary" if I used [color]="btnActive" and set btnActive = "secondary".

Comment: @Yamona, please check the updated answer and also the link

Comment: This is the correct answer. But I edit it to be more specific answer/code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `[style.background-color]` in button.

### html

```
<div *ngFor="let btn of btnArray;let ind = index">
    <button ion-button [style.background-color]="btn.backgroudColor" (click)="btnActivate(ind)">{{btn.title}}</button>
</div>
```

### ts

```
btnArray = 
[
    {
        "title":"Btn1",
        "backgroudColor":"#ff00ff"
    },
    {
        "title":"Btn2",
        "backgroudColor":"#ff00ff"
    },
    {
        "title":"Btn3",
        "backgroudColor":"#ff00ff"
    }
]
btnActivate(ind)
{
    this.btnArray[ind]['backgroudColor'] = "#ffff00";
}
```

Comment: this will change the color of all the buttons but op ask I want is change the color attribute for the clicked button only

Comment: Button are static or coming dynamically?

Comment: For example if click on first button color changed to XXX and now i am click on second button last clicked button should change to default?

Comment: [style.background-color] or  [color] has the same effect. Please read  jitender comment.

Comment: I have like 23 buttons. This will be very long solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<button id="1" ion-button [ngClass]="{'btnActive': selectedId===1}"(click)="btnActivate(1)">text</button>
<button id="2" ion-button  [ngClass]="{'btnActive': selectedId===2}" (click)="btnActivate(2)">text</button>
```

**Ts**

```
selectedId:number= 1;
btnActivate(id:number)
{
   this.selectedId= id;
}
```

**css**

```
.btnActive
{
 background-color:red
}
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-change-attribute-l4xmbg?file=app/app.component.html)